# Can you use $SCRIPT_ROOT to redirect in Flask?

Tags: flask

I have seen several questions about how to pass javascript variables to the server  when redirecting in Flask from javascript, and quite a few discussions, but nobody suggested using a statement like:

```
window.location.href= $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/edit_element/"+ myJavascriptVariable;
```

$SCRIPT_ROOT being defined as:

```
var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
```

which seems to work in my development environment. Is this a correct way to redirect or should I use some combination of url_for?